# Automatic template deduction C++20 with aggregate type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, aggregate-type

I am puzzled about this C++ code:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
  T value;
};
 
int main() {
    return Foo<int>(0).value;
    // Below code works as well in gcc
    // return Foo(0).value;
}
```

It compiles with GCC 10 in C++20 standard (but not in C++17 standard) and latest MSVC, but not with clang 13 or 14, even in C++20.

According to the standard (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)) it should be possible to instantiate `Foo` at least when specifying the templated type.

Why is this related to C++20 ? I see nothing that change in the template deduction specification (I maybe missed something).

Also (this is strange), GCC in C++20 mode even compiles when we call `Foo` without specifying templated type (`Foo(0)`).

**godbolt link** [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6P3ME1cf5)

Comment: This does not look like an aggregate initialization (what you cited with the link) but more like an object constructor call.

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC C++20 allows to construct aggregates with parens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It compiles with GCC 10 in C++20 standard (but not in C++17 standard)
> and latest MSVC.

This is because GCC 10 and the latest MSVC implement [allow initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html), which allows us to use *parentheses* to initialize aggregates.

> Also (this is strange), GCC in C++20 mode even compiles when we call
> Foo without specifying templated type (`Foo(0)`).

This is because GCC 10 implements [class template argument deduction for aggregates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1816r0.pdf), which makes `T` automatically deduced to `int`.

---

Please note that clang does not currently implement these two C++20 features, so your code cannot be accepted by clang.

You can refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) to get the current compiler's support for C++20 features.

Comment: Here, it is said that Clang hasn't yet implemented P2082R1: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support, as well as here: https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html.

Answer (score -5):

Regarding your link, the compiler will tell you what's wrong with your call:

> error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo(int)'

So, the problem is that you try to call a non-existing constructor. Your class `Foo` has the default constructor `Foo()` only.

Just change `return Foo<int>(0).value;` to `return Foo<int>().value;` and it would work. Otherwise you would need a constructor like `Foo(T) {}`.

Comment: C++20 [allows such an initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/oebWK84Ez. Note that `X` doesn't have any converting constructor from `int`.

Comment: The issue is related to aggregates and C++20 implementations.